# Как сохранить Form в файл?

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет, недавно решил научиться делать программы в  WinForms и вот такой вопрос назрел, как сохранить изменённую форму в файл, вот пример моего когда:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                 GlobalsForm1.button1WasClicked = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalsForm1.button2WasClicked = true;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalsForm1.button4WasClicked = true;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalsForm1.button3WasClicked = true;
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GlobalsForm1.button4WasClicked == true)
            {
                button4.Text = textBox1.Text;
                GlobalsForm1.button4WasClicked = false;
            }
            else if (GlobalsForm1.button3WasClicked == true)
            {
                button3.Text = textBox1.Text;
                GlobalsForm1.button3WasClicked = false;
            }
            else if (GlobalsForm1.button2WasClicked == true)
            {
                button2.Text = textBox1.Text;
                GlobalsForm1.button2WasClicked = false;
            }
            else if (GlobalsForm1.button1WasClicked == true)
            {
                button1.Text = textBox1.Text;
                GlobalsForm1.button1WasClicked = false;
            }
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    } }
```

Если надо дополнить, скажите, это просто мой  первый вопрос на этом портале)

UPD: глобальные переменные я объявлял в program.cs

Comment: Глобальные переменные не нужны. Сохранять в файл форму не надо. Надо создать модель приложения: классы для хранения информации и работы с ней. Надо создать визуальн. интерфейс для отображения экземпляров этих классов и работы с ними. Надо создать класс для сохранения в файл или в базу данных состояния модели приложения.

Comment: Если честно,  я вообще не представляю как это всё сделать

Comment: Тогда посмотрите это [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6RNy3rPZpg) для начала.

Comment: Хорошо, посмотрю

Comment: Я наверное скажу, для чего я всё это делаю. Хочу сделать программу, в которой учитель создаёт тест(вопросы к нему), сам тест можно будет запускать на интерактивной доске. Так вот, я хотел для начала сделать заготовленных 5 форм с кнопками, которые можно изменить при запуске. после изменения этих форм, они сохраняются в файл, который укажет сам учитель, чтобы запускать их, я напишу костыль .exe . Для чего отдельный .exe и вообще, зачем создавать отдельный файл для теста? В планах, чтобы этот тест можно было заливать на сайт и запускать на других компьютерах.

Comment: Форма - это элемент пользовательского интерфейса, его не сохраняют. Если вам надо сохранить тест, то и сохраняйте тест, а не форму, на котором этот тест показан.

Comment: Если вы делаете программу для учителей, то наверняка слышали про [Hot Potatoes](https://hotpot.uvic.ca/). Суть этой программы в создание тестов и дальнейшей публикации их в нужном виде (HTML). Так вот, к чему это я, при сохранение теста в виде файла - создается обычный XML  формат, который легко можно прочитать дальше где нам угодно (я даже покажу вам этот [файл](https://hastebin.com/emoxeyofum.xml). То есть другим языком - не одна программа не сохраняет UI (форму), ибо это не рационально и много лишней мороки. Сохраняются данные, которые отображаются на форме и затем читаются где надо.

Comment: Так а если тест сам состоит из форм?

Comment: Немного слышал про HotPotates, но я хотел сделать типо клиента именно .exe, а не в интернете

Comment: @Даниил А при чем тут интернет? Я вам сказал путь того, как правильно делать. Не сохраняйте форму, сохраняйте данные формы. Вот к примеру у вас окно, в нем кнопочек куча, всякий текст и по середине вы пишете вопрос `1+1=?` и дальше по порядку варианты ответа (`2`, `4`, `6`, `8`). Вы жмете кнопку сохранить, у вас создается некий файл, который не содержит в себе все не нужные кнопочки, а содержит всего лишь список вопросов и ответы на них, все. Далее вы в другой программе открываете этот файл, программа считывает его и генерирует свой UI (интерфейс) на основе тех данных, что там есть.

Comment: Но не как вы не передаете всю форму, зачем вам знать цвет формы, размер  формы, разные технические данные формы, мб у вас там Lable с текстом `Version 1.0.0.0`, зачем вам это знать в другом приложение, которому нужны всего лишь данные вопросов/ответов? Передавайте только необходимые данные, не более... Отвечая на вопрос `Так а если тест сам состоит из форм?` - значит ваш подход в корне не верный. UI у всех приложений свой, он не передается. P.S. Что бы уведомить любого из участников, то сделайте пометку через `@Ник` (а то я чудом сюда зашел, не видел ваших сообщений).

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо за совет, попробую так сделать